# Fullcalendar center mouse cursor on event while dragging and scrolling together

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

There is a way to center the mouse cursor pointer on the event while dragging and scrolling together ?

I want it to behave like its working on google calendar :)

When I drag and scroll, the mouse cursor is getting out of the event box and the user can't drag the event to the hours on the top of the page.

Example of the problem:

[image]

Reproduce link (on day view) : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing-demo

Thanks

Comment: Please upload sample code that demonstrates your problem to assist others in answering your question.

Comment: You can reproduce it on day view here : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing-demo

Comment: On trying the google version, it appears that the mouse position is tracked over the whole of the viewport - not just the calendar. After the mousedown, move to the far left for example, and move up and down, it still scrolls the calendar. Maybe try detecting whether the mouse is in the upper or lower half of the window rather than the control itself?

Comment: I think you'd have to raise this as a bug with the fullCalendar maintainers, there isn't just some option you can set to change it AFAIK.  See https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs